# Intersection Mathematica and SMT

Tags: constraint

recently i started to investigate in SMT-solvers (SAT Modulo Theory), especially Z3. My interest is in using it as a constraint solver on mixed integer/boolean problems, with a spoonful of SAT. I am aware that Mathematica has constraint-solving capabilities.
My question is: is there some intersection between SMT-world and Mathematica? Can Mathematica import/export SMTLIB ? 
docs are silent on this...

(the tags available for this question are rather <s>limited</s> constrained...)

Comment: I'm afraid this is probably not enough detail for people to give you a proper answer. Could you give us a sample of what you are trying to do in MMA code?

Comment: i am sure i could write my problem in Mathematica - but i could not use that in other solvers. Some of them have a front-end for Python or an API for Java or C#. The least common denominator is a language called SMTLIB which looks like a simplistic Lisp. If Mathematica could import/export or otherwise interact with SMT, comparisons of results or performance would be possible.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know Mathematica does not yet support that format, nevertheless there are tools like Tarski (see [1]), that takes SMT files and output in Mathematica syntax (as many other functionalities).

---

References:
[1] Vale-Enriquez F., Brown C.W. (2018) Polynomial Constraints and Unsat Cores in Tarski. In: Davenport J., Kauers M., Labahn G., Urban J. (eds) Mathematical Software – ICMS 2018. ICMS 2018. Lecture Notes in Computer Science, vol 10931. Springer, Cham

Comment: Mathematica also has the [SatisfiabilityInstances](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SatisfiabilityInstances.html) and [FindInstance](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance.html) functions to generate solutions of boolean formulas.